# Find items if not equal between lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I Have 2 ArrayList in my project. I want to get items which is not equal.

For Example:

LIST 1 - LIST 2

AB ------- AB

BA ------- BA

CC

I wanna get this CC. I'm doing like this:

```
ArrayList<String> alllist= new ArrayList<>(ArrayList<String> 1);
for (String i : ArrayList<String> 1) {
                for (String j :  ArrayList<String> 2) {
                    if (i.equals(j)) {
                        alllist.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This work if I haved 3 or 4 items in ArrayList but when I add 200 items this method doesn't work fine and getting wrong list.

Any idea? what can I do more?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I'm trying like this:" please show the actual code you're trying, not pseudocode.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the items which are only in one of the lists, or all the items which only appear in list 1 or list 2 but not both?

Comment: which are only in one of the lists @Andy Turner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need everything in list 1 but not list 2

1)  Walk the first list and add each element to a HashSet.

2) use set.removeAll(list2) to remove everything in list 2.

The remainder is what's in list1 and not list2.

If you need to get everything in either list not in the other, you can repeat that in reverse.  This should reverse the operation to O(n+m) where n is the length of list 1 and m is the length of list 2.  Your pseudocode is O(n*m).

```
HashSet firstButNotSecond = new HashSet(list1);
firstButNotSecond.removeAll(list2);
HashSet secondButNotFirst = new HashSet(list2);
secondButNotFirst.removeAll(list1);
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to write a loop for step 1. Just call the correct constructor to do it for you.

Comment: Also note that `removeAll()` is also available on `List`.

Comment: It is, but it will run much slower on a list, as the contains check is O(n), not O(1) for a hash

Comment: [Looking at the source code of `ArrayList`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l699), you'd want to use `list.removeAll(set)`, since `contains` is invoked on the set. For [`HashSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractSet.java#l168), `set.removeAll(list)` invokes contains on the list; and that's O(n).

Comment: @AndyTurner Interestingly you may be right.  Looked at the open JDK code of HashSet and AbstractSet, where the contains happens depends on the size of the two collections.  Which I get where they're going with that, but it leads to mediocre performance.  So I'd say this is the quick way to write it, but if you need it to perform well write the removeAll loop yourself to take advantage of the speedier class.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference). You can use `CollectionUtils.disjunction` from [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)

**Given:**

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("AB", "BA", "DD");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("AB", "BA", "CC");
```

**Action:**

```
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.disjunction(list1, list2));
```

**Result:**

```
[DD, CC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList(); 
list2.add("AB");
list2.add("BA");
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("AB");
list1.add("BA");
list1.add("C");
//remove all the element from the list1 which are also in list2 
list1.removeAll(list2);
System.out.println("Result: " + list1); //only C will left behind
```